# Upload (POST) Content on ArcGIS Enterprise using Python

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise, post

I have developed a script using the ArcGIS API for Python in order to add content and publish data onto ArcGIS Portal. However, I am looking for a methodology to move this data through a REST API instead. The only information I can find on accomplishing this task is here: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/upload.htm. The example that Esri provides simply shows how to use a UI for the Upload of data.

This is the current ArcGIS API for Python script that I have. How can it be modified to Upload data using the Upload function rather than the add content then publish method?

```
#import modules   
from arcgis.gis import GIS  # conda install arcgis -c esri   
import os   
from pathlib import Path   
import zipfile from zipfile 
import ZipFile   
import requests   
import warnings from urllib3.exceptions   
import InsecureRequestWarning

#supress single warning for insecure request   
service = 'https://service/portal/home/'
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)

#create local variables   
gis = GIS(url = service, 
username = "user", password = "pass", verify_cert = False)   
folder = "E:/API_creation/upload"   
   
shpfiles = []   

shpfilesreqext = {"shp", "shx", "dbf", "prj"}

try:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".zip"):
                zipfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))

    #find zipped gdb files
    for zip_path in zipfiles:
        zip_f = ZipFile(zip_path)
        for name in zip_f.namelist():
            if name.endswith('.gdb/'):
                #append gdb folder to gdbfiles list
                gdbfiles.append(os.path.join(zip_path))
                break
            else:
                if zip_path in shpfiles or zip_path in badzipfiles:
                    break
                else:    
                    #check for valid shp extensions
                    file_exts = set()
                    for filename in zip_f.namelist():
                        file_exts.add(filename.split('.')[-1])
                    #append valid shp folder to shpfiles list
                    if shpfilesreqext.issubset(file_exts):
                        shpfiles.append(zip_path)
                    else:
                        badzipfiles.append(zip_path)    

    print(gdbfiles)
    print(shpfiles)
    
    #iterate each shp zip in the list
    for file in shpfiles:
        #grab name of file
        filename = Path(file).stem
        print(filename)
            
        #add shapefile content to portal
        shp = gis.content.add(
            item_properties = {
                "type": "Shapefile", 
                "title": filename,
                "description": "Just a random Study Area",
                "tags": "Clip Area, Study Area",
            },
            data = file,
        )
        print(file + " uploaded successfully")
            
        #publish shapefile on portal
        feature_layer = shp.publish(
            publish_parameters = {
                "name": filename,
            },
            file_type = "Shapefile",
        )
        print(file + " published successfully")  

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking. If you're using the ArcGIS Python API, you're moving data up to Enterprise via a REST API. It's just Python code facilitating that movement through REST. Are you saying the Python code you have is not working? Did you see https://developers.arcgis.com/python/sample-notebooks/publishing-sd-shapefiles-and-csv/

Comment: How can it be modified to move data from one server to another? I have a website that intakes data and would like data to be moved from that website GUI directly onto Portal. I need to create a direct connection, so that the intermediate manual effort of running this script can be taken out of the workflow.

Comment: Yes I have seen that documentation.

Comment: You're asking how to invoke a python script from say a button press on a website? Or you're asking how to have the website (via HTML, JavaScript, etc) make requests to Enterprise? Your issue is very clear to you, but I think you need to step back and try to explain it from the beginning - your ask is not clear.

Comment: Good point. The best way to describe my ask - how do I have a website endpoint make calls to Enterprise? Use case: we have customers who are submitting data through a form and I would like that endpoint to connect to Enterprise, so that the data can flow from one endpoint to another. Specifically, I am looking at the Upload function provided in the link I posted and am wondering how it can be invoked in a script rather than a UI. Does that help clarify a bit?

Comment: if your client is a website go with the javascript sdk + if you need to process complex stuff on the server and you do not have your own backend server-side application you could write a geoprocessing tool, host it as a webtool in portal and call its endpoint from the website.